# Simple responsive website header based on existing code

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, responsive

I initially asked this elsewhere but the code has since been modified and trimmed down to make it easier to work with hence reposting.

```css
body, html {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 0vw;
}

.header {
background-color: #ffffff;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
height: 10vh;
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: solid;
}

.headerfill {
height: 10vh;
border: none;
}

.header-container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-container {
float: left;
width: 40%;
padding-left: 1vh;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: left;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.logo {
height:8vh;
max-width: 80vw; 
padding-top:1vh;
padding-bottom:1vh;
padding-left:4vh;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
}

img{
-webkit-user-drag: none;
}

.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2.5vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}
}

.nav:hover {
color: #096e67;
}

a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 4vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 4vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 2vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Website Header</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<div class="header-container">
<div class="logo-container">
<img class="logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
<div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
<p class="nav">Page1</p>
<p class="nav">Page2</p>
<p class="nav">Page3</p>
<p class="nav">Page4</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Image of how the header would work.]
I initially set it up with two headers and just hid the desktop one on mobile and the mobile one on the desktop. I can't do this and it only needs minor adjustments. Just need the functionality.

I know that I could use a button (then style to show the ☰ and ✘) but I don't know how to use the same page links on both mobile and desktop to be responsive. You can just copy my code to your answer, I know I'll likely need listeners and JavaScript but just can't figure it out with the design I already have.

Thanks in advance :)

```
UPDATE
```

Below is a functional idea of what I need to happen, I have no idea how to incorporate it into my design.

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('nav')
document.querySelector('button')
 .addEventListener('click', e => {
   menu.classList.toggle('active')
  })
```

```css
header{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: #ccc;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
nav{
  display: flex;
}
nav a{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
button{
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {  
  nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    display: none;
  }
  nav.active{
    display: block;
  }
  button{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="" class="logo">logo</a>
  <button>menu</button>
  <nav>
    <a href="">Page1</a>
    <a href="">Page2</a>
    <a href="">Page3</a>
    <a href="">Page4</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I need the functionality of that to match with the image above and the design in my initial code snippet.

```
UPDATE 2
```

Progress:

The idea for this is to replicate the look of mobile websites and have just one responsive header. I'd tried having two versions of the header. It would've worked by hiding the desktop one on mobile and the mobile one on desktop, hence the repost as the code has changed significantly enough.

All I need now is for the `☰` button to be hidden when in view on desktop and the `|  Page1  Page2  Page3  Page4  |` to be hidden on mobile but when the button is clicked there would be a drop-down with the page list. I could use `Before::` and `after::` but I've attempted this with an `event listener` rather than using `Bootstrap` as I'm not all that familiar.

The code is as follows:

```css
body, html {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 0vw;
}

.header {
background-color: #ffffff;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
height: 10vh;
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: solid;
}

.headerfill {
height: 10vh;
border: none;
}

.header-container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-container {
float: left;
width: 40%;
padding-left: 1vh;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: left;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.logo {
height:8vh;
max-width: 80vw; 
padding-top:1vh;
padding-bottom:1vh;
padding-left:4vh;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
}

img{
-webkit-user-drag: none;
}

.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2.5vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}
}

.nav:hover {
color: #096e67;
}

a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 4vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 4vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 2vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Website Header</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheet3.2.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
<div class="header">
<div class="header-container">
<div class="logo-container">
<img class="logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
<div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
<button>☰</button>
<p class="nav">Page1</p>
<p class="nav">Page2</p>
<p class="nav">Page3</p>
<p class="nav">Page4</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<script>
let menu = document.querySelector('nav')
document.querySelector('button')
 .addEventListener('click', e => {
   menu.classList.toggle('active')
  })
</script>
```

I think it's something to do with class lists? I can get pages to appear when the button is clicked although doing so messes with the design on the desktop and the page names no longer display horizontally. You should be able to copy my code to your answer, or just provide some guidance. Anything would be appreciated, I've spent hours on this and can't get it to work.

Hopefully the image above will help, please make the code I have created functional as this is the design I wish to opt for and the one that I am sticking with. The page is set to show the button at 500px with `media queries` If someone could tell me why this isn't working that'd be amazing.

All that's left to do is to; get the button to hide on desktop, get the button to display on mobile and on mobile make clicking the button display the page list, like in the image. Wrapping the page list with `<nav></nav>` tags ruins the desktop formatting.

Fiddle of the latest version [Fiddle of the latest version (with button)](https://jsfiddle.net/helpmeplease1/fu9dgezo/)

I'm stuck, please help. Thanks in advance :)

```
UPDATE 3
```

I've managed to obtain some functionality but there is no styling on the drop-down itself and now the page titles stack on desktop too. The icons also don't switch.

```css
body, html {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 0vw;
}

.header {
background-color: #ffffff;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
height: 10vh;
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: solid;
}

.headerfill {
height: 10vh;
border: none;
}

.header-container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-container {
float: left;
width: 40%;
padding-left: 1vh;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: left;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}


media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
nav.active{
            display: block;
        }
        }
    

.logo {
height:8vh;
max-width: 80vw; 
padding-top:1vh;
padding-bottom:1vh;
padding-left:4vh;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
}

img{
-webkit-user-drag: none;
}

.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2.5vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}
}

.nav:hover {
color: #096e67;
}

a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 4vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 4vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 2vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}
   
    button{
        display: none;
    }

    @media (max-width: 500px) {
        nav{
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: right;
            display: none;
        }
        nav.active{
            display: block;
        }
        button{
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Website Header</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<header>
<div class="header">
<div class="header-container">
<div class="logo-container">
<img class="logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
<div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
<button>☰</button>
<nav>
<p class="nav">Page1</p>
<p class="nav">Page2</p>
<p class="nav">Page3</p>
<p class="nav">Page4</p>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<script>
let menu = document.querySelector('nav')
document.querySelector('button')
 .addEventListener('click', e => {
   menu.classList.toggle('active')
  })
</script>
```

It's almost there. Please help, it would be appreciated :)

```
Update 4
```

I've got the button back with the horizontal alignment.

The final code I have is;

```css
body, html {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0vw;
    margin: 0vw;
}

.header {
background-color: #ffffff;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
height: 10vh;
z-index: 1;
border-bottom: solid;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.headerfill {
height: 10vh;
border: none;
}

.header-container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-container {
float: left;
width: 40%;
padding-left: 1vh;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: left;
}

.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.logo {
height:8vh;
max-width: 80vw; 
padding-top:1vh;
padding-bottom:1vh;
padding-left:4vh;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
}

img{
-webkit-user-drag: none;
}

.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 2vh;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 2vh;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}
}

.nav:hover {
color: #096e67;
}

a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 4vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 4vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 8vw;
text-align: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
color: #000000;
padding-left: 2vh;
padding-right: 2vh;
padding-bottom: 0.5vh;
line-height: 1em;
}
}


    nav{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: right;
    }
    nav a{
        display:block;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
        font-size: 2vw;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        color: #000000;
        padding-left: auto;
        padding-right: auto;
        line-height: 1em;
        object-fit: contain;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    i{
        display: none !important;
    }
 
    @media (max-width: 400px) {
        nav{
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;

            display: none;

            font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
            font-size: 2.5vw;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            color: #000000;
            padding-left: auto;
            padding-right: auto;
            line-height: 1em;
            object-fit: contain;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        nav.active{
            display: block;
        }
        i{
            display: block!important;
            margin:5px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Website Header</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<header>
<div class="header">
<div class="header-container">
<div class="logo-container">
<img class="logo" src="/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
<div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
<nav>
<p class="nav">Page1</p>
<p class="nav">Page2</p>
<p class="nav">Page3</p>
<p class="nav">Page4</p>
</nav>
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<script>
menu = document.querySelector('nav');
    document.querySelector('i')
        .addEventListener('click', e => {
        menu.classList.toggle('active')
    document.querySelector('header i').classList.toggle('fa-bars')
    document.querySelector('header i').classList.toggle('fa-times')
    })
</script>
```

I just wonder why when resizing the browser window at points the text goes much larger? is there something I've defined twice or is there redundant code I've not spotted? Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I provided the image as a resource as to what I'm going for. The one labelled "Desktop" already works. I need to be able to get the "Mobile" view to work where the pages turn into a dropdown.

Comment: @ksav I've added functional code below as an example, I need that to happen to my code.

Comment: You might want to take a read of this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Resolved with the help of @Phil so there's no need for me to take a look, ksav. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Your "functional idea" definitely works. I just introduce button icons via fontawesome.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
    header{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        background: #ccc;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    nav{
        display: flex;
    }
    nav a{
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #ddd;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
    }
    button{
        display: none;
    }

    @media (max-width: 400px) {
        nav{
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: right;
            display: none;
        }
        nav.active{
            display: block;
        }
        button{
            display: block;
        }
    }

</style>
<header>
    <a href="" class="logo">logo</a>
    <button><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    <nav>
        <a href="">Page1</a>
        <a href="">Page2</a>
        <a href="">Page3</a>
        <a href="">Page4</a>
    </nav>
</header>
<script>
    menu = document.querySelector('nav');
    document.querySelector('button')
        .addEventListener('click', e => {
        menu.classList.toggle('active')
    document.querySelector('button i').classList.toggle('fa-bars')
    document.querySelector('button i').classList.toggle('fa-times')
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Phil. I've added a section in the question called `update 2` to further demonstrate my progress & what I'm looking for. I've added the button etc. The functional idea is good in concept but I really need it to be applied to the main design. I've added it as a fiddle here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/helpmeplease1/fu9dgezo/) if that's more helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried the code above? It should meet all your requirements. You could also replace the button with icons directly. I didn't know what you are trying to improve.

Comment: Yes, it did work as a concept. I'm just not sure how to get it to work with [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/helpmeplease1/fu9dgezo/) I understand the concept, just can't get the two to work together. I'd greatly appreciate if you could take a look at that fiddle and potentially add the same functionality because I'm so lost and have spent more time than I'd care to admit trying to get this to work, Thank you :)

Comment: I have still got nothing. I just need the functionality of your answer added to my design. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helpmeplease1/fu9dgezo/)

Comment: you may check the fiddle. You may continue to improve the style when the dropdown displays.

Comment: Please see `Update 3` in the original question, some functionality is there but the horizontal alignment is gone and the drop-downs aren't in their own box

Comment: Thank you, @Phil. I have combined the two with some modifiers. I think there may be redundant code as when resizing in `update 4` there's an issue with text size. Would appreciate if you could check it. Thanks :)